# ReactJS - Nested tags, variables and text in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm unable to fix this simple JSX tag

```
<>
   {disabled?<b>{label}</b>:'Please enter'+ <b>{label}</b>}
</>
```

What I want is display variable `label(in bold)` if disabled is true

And display `Please enter label(in bold)` otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Please enter` needs to be written as JSX, not as a string that gets concatenated:

```
{disabled ? <b>{label}</b> : <>Please enter<b>{label}</b></>}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSX can return only a single node (or array). Return the second bit in a fragment or some other tag, like div or span.

```
<>
  {disabled ? (
    <b>{label}</b>
  ) : (
    <>
      Please enter <b>{label}</b>
    </>
  )}
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a single HTML/JSX element.

Something like the below should work:

```
<>
   {disabled ? <b>{label}</b> : <span>Please enter <b>{label}</b><span>}
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the concept of passing JSX to Children Easy to understand this concept....

<>
{
disabled?
**{label}**
:'Please enter'+ **{label}**
}
</>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).